# Is it possible to use a Data context in the immediate window of Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to debug C# Linq 2 SQL code, and i'm getting a "System.NotSupportedException" exception when using Last() on a table. Is it not possible to use this operator in the Immediate windows of Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: I think it's more likely that Linq to SQL does not have a translation for .Last into valid SQL.

Comment: Can you please put your code here and describe in details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried a quick test using LinqPad and can confirm that Linq to SQL does not have a translation for `.Last()`, instead it throws an exception with the message "The query operator 'Last' is not supported."

If you have a incremental type primary id such an integere or another field that's indexed and easy to order by, instead perhaps try doing a `.OrderByDescending(x => x.id).First()`